# Webpack cannot resolve image

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-2

I have searched all over the place. But I still couldn't fix my issue. Can someone please help me with this. I am keep getting an error message can't resolve my image file. I doubt it must something to do with relative or absolute path, because I am importing my scss file into another sass file. It also doesn't give an error saying you need a proper loader to handle this type.

[image]

```
This is my webpack config.
`{test: /\.(jpe?g|png|gif|svg)$/i,
    use: 'file-loader'
  },
  {
    test: /.scss$/,
    use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
      fallback: 'style-loader',
      use: 'css-loader!resolve-url-loader!sass-loader',
      publicPath: '/'
    })
  },`
```

I am using @import to load that into another SASS file.

```
&:after { background: url('./images/themeTab.png') no-repeat center;}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to know how to rewrite urls, `resolve-url-loader` [needs source maps enabled](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader#source-maps-required) on any preceding loader.

Change your `.scss` loader chain like:

```
  use: 'css-loader!resolve-url-loader!sass-loader?sourceMap',
```